# Soldering Station Extras?

Tags: soldering

I recently bought a cheap soldering hotter and solder iron station from E-bay. It came with lots of extras. Sadly it never came with any good tips, but it did come with these..[image: Alien parts!!]

What are these for?

Thanks 
Student

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are replacement heater cartridges, from the number of wires likely with built in sensing.

Looks like the small one is for an iron, and the larger for a hot air tool or something else.